# Is there a simple way to apply grammatical casing to a string?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I am developing a `Xamarin.Forms` application on `UWP`

I have an `Editor` control - Basically a multi-line `TextBox`

I am trying to apply some simple grammatical casing to the string basically the following:

- Capitalise the word "I"
- Capitalise the First word
- Capitalise the First word after a full stop.

I have managed to do the first two, and am a bit stuck on the third and was wondering if there is an easier way or whether my algorithm can be adapted.

What I have so far is:

```
    public static string ToGramaticalCase(this string s)
    {
        var thingsToCapitalise = new String[] {"i"};

        string newString = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            var wordSplit = s.Split(' ');
            if (wordSplit.Count() > 1)
            {
                var wordToCapitalise = wordSplit.First();
                wordToCapitalise = wordToCapitalise.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + wordToCapitalise.Substring(1);
                var value = wordToCapitalise + s.Substring(wordToCapitalise.Length);
                foreach (var item in thingsToCapitalise)
                {
                    value = value.Replace(string.Format(" {0} ", item), string.Format(" {0} ", item.ToUpper()));
                }
                newString = value;
            }

        }
        return newString;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it does everything you want, but did you look at [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will capitalize all words after ". ":

```
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var result = NewSentenceWithUpperLetter("Sentence one. sentence two.");
            // result will be 'Sentence one. Sentence two.'
        }

        private string NewSentenceWithUpperLetter(string text)
        {
            var splitted = text.Split(' ');
            for (var i = 1; i < splitted.Length; i++)
            {
                if (splitted[i - 1].EndsWith("."))
                {
                    splitted[i] = splitted[i][0].ToString().ToUpper() + splitted[i].Substring(1);
                }
            }

            return string.Join(" ", splitted);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string also on full stop. Change this line:

```
var wordSplit = s.Split(' ');
```

Into this:

```
var wordSplit = s.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Edit**

This extension method would do what you want:

```
public static string ToTitleCase(this string input)
{
    string output = 
      String.Join(" ", input.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(x => x = x.Length>1?
                                 x.First().ToString().ToUpper() + x.Substring(1): 
                                 x.First().ToString().ToUpper()));
    output = 
      String.Join(".", output.Split(new char[] { '.' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .ToList()
                        .Select(x => x = x.Length > 1 ?
                                x.First().ToString().ToUpper() + x.Substring(1) : 
                                x.First().ToString().ToUpper()));
    return output;
}
```

Test string: `string input = "i try this test sentence  .now it works as i want";`

Output: `I Try This Test Sentence .Now It Works As I Want`

Comment: `wordsplit` is currently only used to get the First word of the string, do I need another `ForEach`? Could you do a `dotnetfiddle`?

Comment: No,just change the line i told you. It should work just fine (although i didn't tested it)

Comment: Wait,now i see the problem. It won't join the sentence as it should. Let me think about it

Comment: See my updated answer. I think now works as it should